# Inconsistent JArray how to count

Tags: c#, json.net

I have an inconsistent JArray items like below, sometimes it has event property, but I need to count based on event value.

```
[
  {
    "id": 114792,
    "attributes": {
      "priority": 0
     }
   },
  {
    "id": 114792,
    "attributes": {
      "priority": 0,
      "event": 10
     }
   },
   {
    "id": 114793,
    "attributes": {
      "priority": 0,
      "event": 0
     }
   }
]
```

How to count based on criteria for example event = 0?
I tried below:

```
_ja.Select(x => x.ToObject<JObject>()).Where(x => (int)x["attributes"]["event"] == 0).Count();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. just add the null condition in the `Where`.

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/21fLG9) is the working code

```
_ja.Select(x => x.ToObject<JObject>())
   .Where(x => x["attributes"]["event"] != null && (int)x["attributes"]["event"] == 0).Count();
```